# Can you find derivative by substituting and replacing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I wanted to find derivative of
$$
    y= \frac{3x + 5 }{x^2}
$$
I thought of replacing that $x$ by $k^2$.
And as $dx > 0$,$ dk >0$. So I could after getting answer,  replace $k^2$ by $x$.
However this method doesn't seem to be giving me the correct answer.  I think there's something to do with my misconception that I can consider that way.  But Where am I missing the crucial part?

Comment: How did you calculate the derivative? If you consider $x=x(k) = k^2$, then you have
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dk}\frac{dk}{dx}
$$
which is the chain rule.

Comment: Could you show the steps to reaching your answer?

Comment: I wanted to find it using first principle.

Comment: I am only allowed to use first principle,  so I found dy/dk and replaced k^2 by x.  I think that's illegal but I don't see any better way off.

Comment: Please show us what you did. It is hard to imagine what you mean exactly by "replacing $x$ by $k^2$", and why it matters that $dk>0$ (which, by the way, is wrong) ???

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the independent variable, and apply the chain rule, though I am not sure it really helps in this case.

Doesn't your choice $x=k^2$ also mean you are limiting the domain to non-negative $x$ assuming $k$ is real? Would any formula for the derivative be valid for negative $x$? It may be, but it would need careful reasoning.

I think it is better in this case to think about using the [quotient rule](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-quotient-2009-1.pdf).

Comment: I think it's better to observe that $y=3\frac{1}{x}+5\frac{1}{x^2}$ and apply the power rule.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe yes of course that's also possible/preferable. It doesn't appear the questioner was aware of quotient rule so was drawing attention to it as a basic tool.